# XXHash for PHP (without module/extension)

Tags: php, hash, php-extension

For on online service, I'm currently using XXHash. Now I'm trying to create a plugin for webshops but these shops are all using PHP, mostly on shared hosting platforms. Problem with this is that the available XXHash plugins all require to have XXHash extension installed. Which is something hard to request on shared hosting platforms. Now I'm wondering if I should move away from XXHash to something that has a module less support for hashing or if there is a possibility to have XXHash working on PHP without the use of an extension.
A webservice was one of the ideas but XXHash is used specifically for privacy reasons in our case so this webservice would be a bad solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: "but XXHash is used specifically for privacy reasons" How did you end up with xxhash?

Comment: The entire point of xxhash appears to be blindingly fast execution speed, which you simply won't get with native PHP, so there's little point in such an implementation existing. Also, as PeeHaa is hinting at, xxhash is explicitly *not cryptographic*, i.e. not necessarily a great choice for security purposes.

Comment: XXHash was indeed selected for performance advantages, which is indeed the case for our app and nodejs server. For PHP however, performance is not that big of a deal which is still possible with the module. However, we want to be able to support this "transparantly" and in this case, require XXHash as a PHP library. For privacy reasons we are using it so the app/plugin does not require to send out data itself but these hashes which are used like fingerprints of this data.

Comment: same here. I am trying to make a proof of work algo in javascript and the PHP side doesnt need to be THAT fast  but my tries with SHA1 were quite bad with SHA1 in PHP being over 10 times faster than js, meaning it could be circumvented way too easily by just letting a normal program outside the browser do the hashes. and I want to see how fast I can get the JS side to work so that it cna be at least reasonable.

Comment: I hope you are not using it for hashing passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only alternative seems to be using different language for the hashing function. Maybe compiling the C code used here: https://github.com/mscdex/node-xxhash/blob/master/src/hash_64.hpp and using this together with exec. (For as long as this command isn't blacklisted)

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented in PHP here

https://github.com/exussum12/xxhash

Please remember that xxhash is designed for quick hashing for large files / streams. Please don't use this for passwords.

Also as the repo says if you need additional speed please use the PHP extensions. This is designed for ease of use not speed of execution